# cv2.bitwise_and in python3

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a beginner in python3 and have a wrong situation on combining the processed color image and img_edge

```
import cv2 

num_down = 2
num_bilateral =7

img_rgb = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

img_color = img_rgb
for _ in range(num_down):
    img_color = cv2.pyrDown(img_color)


for _ in range(num_bilateral):
    img_color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_color, d=9,
                                    sigmaColor=9,
                                    sigmaSpace=7) 

for _ in range(num_down):
    img_color = cv2.pyrUp(img_color)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

median = cv2.medianBlur(gray_image, 7) 
img_edge = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(median, 255,
                                 cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
                                 blockSize=9,
                                 C=2)
color_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_edge, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
image = cv2.bitwise_and(color_img,img_edge)
cv2.imshow('Cartoon', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error message says:

error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::binary_o

can someone help me out how to write cv2.bitwise function to make the code runs?

Comment: Some debugging wouldn't hurt. You know where the error occurs (the error message contained that information before you helpfully cut it off), so the first step would be inspecting the input parameters to that function. What is the size and data type (of the elements) of those two arrays? As the message suggest they are probably different sizes -- so next thing to do would be trace through your code and reason why that is the case. (You do understand what the individual statements you wrote do, right? If not, you've got a bigger issue than buggy code.)

Comment: you run it with a 1 channel image and another 3 channeled image...

Comment: yap i found it after posting it. Thanks a lot